# Making a call to a CDN in react-i18next?

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I am attempting to access the resources for my localized app using i18next-resources-to-backend and i18next-chained-backend using the framework recommended here: https://www.i18next.com/how-to/backend-fallback, with the key difference being I am attempting to access the resources from a CDN, not a locale file.

```
.init({
 fallbackLng: 'en',
 namespace: 'resources'
)}
```

```
backend: {
  backends: [
  HttpBackend,
  resourcesToBackend((language, namespace, callback) => {
  import(`./${language}/${namespace}.json`)
   .then(resources => {
    callback(null, resources)
})
.catch(error => {
callback(error, null)
})
 })
]
},
backendOptions: [
{
 loadPath: 'https://url/domain/link/dir/{language}}/{{namespace}}.json'
}
]
```

It is not working and I am getting this error in the console:

> Object { error: Error }: ​error: Error: Cannot find module './es/translation.json'

Anyone have experience with this problem?

Comment: does that file exist?

Comment: is your setup able to import json files?

Comment: @adrai, yes to both. To your second question, I have the resources imported from a locale file as a fallback and `resources` included in the init as well.

Comment: maybe a reproducible example would help

Comment: I'll see what I can do.